# Set selected item background color on Android dropdown navigation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I think this is an easy question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my specific problem.

I've read [this great article](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) and would like to set the background color of the **selected item** on the Android Dropdown list on the stock ActionBar (I'm not using Sherlock and I'm targetting ICS+), as explained in the image link below:

[image: Dropdown list screenshot]

So far I've set my theme in this way:

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>        
  </style>
  <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And this is my **ad_selectable_background.xml**:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

My dropdown view resource is:

```java
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

The **pressed** state works, but when you open the menu no selection is displayed.
I would like to set it to **holo_blue_light** using the selector, but I'm not able to find the correct syntax **using XML**.

I'm looking for an XML only answer if it's possible (i.e. not using any code). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it was quite simple!

I had to edit **ad_selectable_background.xml** to use the **checked** state (as I did before, but I was missing the theme below):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And then edit the **theme** by adding the **android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle** item and disabiling the **checkMark** (as I didn't want the radio buttons), in this way:

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerDropDownItem</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MySpinnerDropDownItem" parent="android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">@null</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```