# Highlight an item in drop down menu based on system calendar - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, highlight, android-calendar

I have a menu xml(menu_year.xml) with 10 years and this menu is shown on clicking a button(yearbutton). How can I highlight current year (year got from system calendar) by default in the menu?

This is my menu_year.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2020"
    android:title="2020"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2019"
    android:title="2019"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2018"
    android:title="2018"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2017"
    android:title="2017"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2016"
    android:title="2016"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2015"
    android:title="2015"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2014"
    android:title="2014"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2013"
    android:title="2013"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2012"
    android:title="2012"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/year2011"
    android:title="2011"/>
```

This is my java code

```
Button yearbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yearbutton);
yearbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final PopupMenu popup_year = new PopupMenu(DateTimeSelect_Activity.this, yearbutton);
            popup_year.getMenuInflater()
                    .inflate(R.menu.menu_year, popup_year.getMenu());
            popup_year.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    yearvalue.setText(item.getTitle());
                    yearvalue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup_year.show();
        }
    });
```

How can I highlight the year 2016 in the drop down on clicking yearbutton?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to use a menu with an actionLayout to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your answer. Can you please explain a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered for this question 
[Set selected item background color on Android dropdown navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846687/set-selected-item-background-color-on-android-dropdown-navigation)
check this for the backround color of the pop up menu.

Comment: I am not asking about highlighting the selected item. I am asking about highlighting an item based on system calendar. For eg., suppose if I am clicking year button today then the year 2016 should be highlighted and if I am clicking the button with system date 2017 then 2017 should be highlighted. Can you help me with this requirement?